# Java variable of an Object acess as generic

Tags: java

I have java object

```
public class ClientDuplicationVerificationData {

    public final String firstname;
    public final String middlename;
    public final String lastname;
    public final String fullname;
    public final String displayName;
    public final String mobileNo;
    public final LocalDate dateOfBirth;
    public final CodeValue gender;
}
```

I just need to access one of the variable as generic 
for example

```
String variable = "middlename";
ClientDuplicationVerificationData clientDuplicationVerificationData  =  new ClientDuplicationVerificationData ();

clientDuplicationVerificationData.variable;
```

According to some conditions the variable may be changing.

sometimes it may be `lastName`,`gennder`,`dateOfBirth` and so on

is there any way to do this?

Comment: Or use apache commons fieldutils...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Class.getDeclaredFields()` to get all declared fields of the class. You can use `Field.get(currentObject)` to get the value of the `currentObject`.

In your example it would be like this

```
clientDuplicationVerificationData.getClass().getDeclaredField(variable).get(clientDuplicationVerificationData);
```